# Is it possible to stop a libxml parser while the process is running?

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I am using a libxml parser for quick downloading and display. My problem is in some cases I need to stop the parser while it is processing. Is it possible to do? Can you guys please suggest me on this.

Thanks in advance,
Sekhar Bethalam.

Answer (score 5):

The SAX2/libxml2 API has the `xmlStopParser`-function that might be useful in this case.

Specified in the docs as `void xmlStopParser(xmlParserCtxtPtr context)`.

The documentation is available here:
http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-parser.html#xmlStopParser

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the SAX push interface (created with `xmlCreatePushParserCtxt()`) you can somehow signal to the controlling code that you wish to abort, and it can stop calling `xmlParseChunk()`.  In this way you can stop the parsing at the end of the current 'chunk'.

If you need to abort immediately, you can probably achieve it by throwing an exception within the callback.